# Retrieving pandas dataframe from open excel file level

Tags: python, excel, vba, jupyter-notebook

I would like to use a VBA macro in an excel spreadsheet that pastes specific dataframe from my jupyter notebook into this spreadheet.

I tried what was suggested in other thread but the code doesn't say how to specify a df that I need.

This is what I used

```vb
Sub DataFrameImport()
  'RUN PYTHON TO EXPORT DATA FRAME
  Shell "C:\pathTo\python.exe fullpathOfPythonScript.py", vbNormalFocus

  'CLEAR EXISTING CONTENT
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5).Cells.Clear

  'COPY AND PASTE TO WORKBOOK
  Workbooks("PythonExport").Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5).Range("A1").Select
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5).Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: why wouldn't you use python to add it to the file? And does it have to be an existing workbook or can you generate it on the fly with a given name?

Comment: It would be an existing workbook. I wouldn't use python to add this in because I already  have other data on the spreadsheet and would like to have it all working from excel level only without need of opening python.

Comment: why doesn't your python script (that you call) write the df to your workbook?

Comment: It does when I run it on jupyter or spyder, but I would like to run it from excel level if possible

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this library: https://www.xlwings.org/. It allows you to call python from VBA in a very intuitive manner as described in the documentation [here](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/vba.html#).